# Custom Error vs Custom Exception

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, vb6, vb6-migration

I am in the process of updating some `vb6` code to `vb.net`. The error handling in this old code uses `On Error GoTo` or `On Error Resume Next` with error handles at the end of each method.For example:

```
Public Function Init() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_Init
    Init = True
Exit_Init: 
    Exit Function 
Err_Init:
    Init = False
    Resume Exit_Init
End Function
```

Now that I am updating this code to `vb.net` I am changing all error handling to `try - catch` statements. I can either wrap the `Public Sub Main` function in a `try - catch` statement and catch all errors at the top level or swap out the above code for the following:

```
Public Function Init() As Boolean
    Try
        Init = True
    catch e As exception
        Init = false
    End Try
End Function
```

My Problem comes when, in the old code, a custom error is set (`Error 9999`) if certain `If` statements are not met. In the Error handles at the end of the function, it checks if the error is not `9999`. If it is not then it handles it appropriately. Using the first example:

```
Public Function Init() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_Init
    Dim a As Integer
    If (a <> 10)
        Init = True
    Else
        Error 9999
    End If
Exit_Init: 
    Exit Function 
Err_Init:
    If (Err.number() <> 9999)
        Init = False
    End If
    Resume Exit_Init
End Function
```

So my question is, how can I use `try-catch` statements to replicate this `error 9999`, as throughout my code it will not always be the same exception that is thrown, hence why just throwing a custom `error 9999` could be used across the board and used to mark the errors that could be ignored, and then you can just catch the important errors. Is there a way to `Throw New Exception(Id = 9999)`, sort of thing?

Comment: Just make your own `Exception` subclass, and throw it. Then you can add a special `catch` case for it.

Comment: But i didn't want to catch the custom `exception`, i wanted to `catch` everything except it?

Comment: Then just have two catch statements: one for the custom exception (which does nothing) and another for all (remaining) exceptions.

Comment: ah yer, duh. so simple! thanks. Any suggestions on whether to put `try catch`s on each method or simple around the main method to catch all exceptions?

Comment: Handle only those exceptions you need to be able to resume from. All non-recoverable exceptions can be handled by a single global exception handler (like `Application.UnhandledException` event, or try-catch in `Main`, depends on your project type)

Comment: I expect you know this but you could just leave that code unchanged, if you are in a hurry and there is lots of code. [VB.Net supports `On Error Goto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx). Of course it is preferable to update the code to use `try - catch` if you do have the time to make the changes and retest the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom exception and treat separetly in your catch.
Here's some example on how to create your custom exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx

And then code something this way:

```
Public Function Init() As Boolean
     Try
        If (a = 10) Then
          Throw New YourCustomException()
        End If
     Catch yourEx As YourCustomException
        'Do whatever you want to do when the code throws your custom exception            
     Catch generalException As Exception
        Return False
     End Try

     Return True
End Function
```